# when i add a sound file into xcode and played it using uilocalization, it won't work.

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification, alarm

I dragged a "alarm.caf" file into my project,and used

```
notification.soundName = @"alarm.caf";
```

to make it play.

However, it won't make any sounds in the simulator. At the same time, I tried another app (which has the same function), and all goes well. I don't understand at all. I also tried .m4a but it can't figure the problem.
anyone knows about it?

By the way, i want to know that whether ***uilocalnotification*** can be showed in a pop-up style?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I fixed the first problem.
I download a ios-6.1 simulator and it played sound perfectly.
Thought I have no idea why it doesn't work on ios-7 simulator.

Problem 2 is still hanging.